# PHP Comparing Emails

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to compare an Email address stored in a database to one entered in the input however it is not recognizing:

I am trying to select a colum from my db with:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `men` WHERE `Email`=$user_email");
```

however the query returns 0 even though the emails are exactly the same.  What is the issue here

Comment: use `Email`=`'$user_email'`

Comment: For the love of everything that is holy, please don't use the mysql_ functions. use PDO or mysqli!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues.  This query will interpolate to `Email = email@example.com` which is a syntax error in MySQL.

- You should be checking for errors after `mysql_query` with something like `mysql_query($query) or echo mysql_error()`
- You need to wrap `$user_email` in quotes so it interpolates to `Email = 'email@example.com'`, which is the valid/desired query.
- You should not even be using [`ext/mysql`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) at all; it is deprecated.  See big pink box.
- Your code is vulnerable to injection because the query is not properly parameterized.

A much better alternative would be (in PDO):

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `men` WHERE `Email` = ?");
$query->execute(array($user_email));
$result = $query->fetch();
```

Note that my comments about error checking and parameterization still apply to PDO.